# How to add images to the title page of quarto presentation?

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

In a `quarto` `revealjs` presentation using `Rstudio`, I want to add images of the project funders to the title page only. For example, one of the image should be on the left, and the other one on the right (the "1" and "2" on the image shown correspond to the approx. locations where I want to put the photos). Is this possible?

```
---
title: "Boring title"
format: revealjs
---
```

[image]

P.S.: Please note that I am aware of the `logo` option in `quarto` and this is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds) on the `.title` CSS class.

```
---
title: "Boring title"
format: revealjs
css: style.css
---

## First Slide
```

**style.css**

```
h1.title {
  background-image: url(dog.jpg), url(lights.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left, right;
  background-size: 200px, 200px;
}
```

---

[image: two images added left and right side of a seemingly boring title]